# What is my Facebook URL for a like box?

Tags: facebook, href

I am really trying to understand how to add a like box to my website I was able to copy the code for the Facebook platform and paste it into my website programmer, but that was not what I wanted that like box was for people to like Facebook platform.  I want a platform for my website which is www.datgoodstuff.com.
     *I tried to change the url and the Facebook Page URL but this is what pop up: 
     [Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.]*

**Can you please help me out**

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the tools within the facebook developer API where it gives pre-defined plugins for things like like buttons. 
You provide the link to your page/group etc, and facebook with generate the scipt code to insert into your website.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the docs,

> The Like Box is a social plugin that enables Facebook Page owners to attract and gain Likes from their own website.

You need a Facebook fan page not a website to use the Like Box. Consider using the Recent Activity or Recommendations Plugin

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/